# Setting Tpc of gate to 0, what prevents me from doing so?

Tags: verilog, logic-gates, system-verilog

I had the following question when learning logic gates in system verilog but found no answer for it:

We learnt a way to set the Tpc for any gate in code to any value we like, so want prevents me and others to set it to 0 and make things easier and produce the world's first "perfect" processor?

Especially since my professor told me if you do a project in system verilog you can send your design to manufacturers and they can build it for you.

Comment: I printed a new scale for my little VW's speedometer. It goes to 500mph.

Answer (score 3):

You are combining two true but mutually exclusive ideas.

You certainly can set all of your gate delays to zero and you will have the world's fastest processor, but it will only exist in your simulation.

If you want to manufacture a processor you won't be able to set the gate delays arbitrarily. You will have to use the manufacturer's process parameters to estimate the actual, realizable gate delays...and they won't be zero.

Comment: Can you kindly add more info, like when we are talking about TSMS how much low can they go? Plus, what causes this waiting times at all is this a hardware problem, electricity travels in the speed of light so there should be no delay....

Comment: Do you mean TSMC? Their process parameters are proprietary and not public information. The limiting factor is not the propagation of electromagnetic waves in conductors, it is the charging and discharging of parasitic wiring capacitance through non-zero effective resistance of the transistors.